# Pi4B no 1080p output only 1024 x 768

Tags: hdmi, pi-4

I'm running Buster (with Pi-4 options), with an `HP2311 23"` monitor rated as `1920x1080 60Hz`.

The maximum resolution offered is `1024x768`. With the Stretch installed, it is quite happy at `1080p`.

In both cases, I have to set `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` and `config_hdmi_boost=4` in the `config.txt` to get any o/p.

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Change the `config_hdmi_boost=4` to `config_hdmi_boost=2` OR `config_hdmi_boost=7`. What happened?

Comment: You should split the question and the answer.

Comment: Thanks  M. Rostami, I'll try that at the weekend.

Comment: Dmitry Grigoryev, I originally thought I'd posted the question but one of my Tags had prevented the post so I couldn't answer it and decided to include my solution in the question before posting in case it helped anyone. I do realise that this is the WRONG way to do things but hey life's short at my age!

Comment: Having set "advanced options -> resolution -> DMT MODE 82 -> Finish " the config_hdmi_boost=4 doesn't matter. I ended up commenting it off.

Comment: this is a question answer site. Please don't put "solved" in the question title and the solution inside the question. Click the **Answer Your Own Question** button below and write your solution in as an answer. After the required wait time accept your answer by clicking on the gray check mark  next to your answer and turn it green ✅. This will help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To fix it I ran sudo raspi-config Then:

advanced options -> resolution -> DMT MODE 82 -> Finish

Then I selected:

preferences -> screen settings -> 1920 1080 16:9"